# Idea for Creating a Program to Solve a Word Prob

Tags: java, logic

So I am working on a word problem, and it goes something like this:

! section removed

I am not posting the exact question or diagram just in case someone cannot stop themselves from posting a direct answer.

I am trying to write a program in Java for this, but I can't really get a grip on how to do this logically. I know I can start of with an array for each square like this:

```
int square1 = //four sides with each liquid value
```

but I do not know how to include the unlimited ones (which are diagonal), or how to continue once I figure it out.

Any help with this programming logic is appreciated.

Comment: You might start by reading up on the maximum flow problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem

Comment: Beautiful. I never would have thought there was such an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say go through each pipe and record the maximum going through it, which should be the lower of its capacity or the sum of the maxima going into it.  The unlimited ones then just take the total going into them (or, at the very beginning, `Integer.MAX_VALUE`).  Or you could use a `bool` for tracking whether it's infinite.  Or, just for fun, `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`.

Note that if there are any cycles in the pipes, you may need to cycle through and update a couple times, until you get a steady answer.

Edit: After looking a bit at the max flow problem linked in a comment and thinking about it, I'm not so sure this is the right way to go, as I don't think it accounts for splitting current between two outgoing pipes.  Perhaps some distant relative of Ohm's law, adapted for water?

Comment: I understand what you are saying for the other lines, but not for the first. How could I get something lower than its capacity if I am recording a maximum?

Comment: If a pipe with an infinite flow capacity has only two pipes leading into it, one with a capacity of ten and another with five, the most that could actually go through that pipe is 15, because it can't be fed more than that.